# Get two values from a bash function in a shared library file

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to create a shared function in bash which will be in a separate library file used by different shell scripts.

The function will read a string value and e.g. "iPhone_7" and return a width and height.

So the function needs to return two values to the calling script.

This is what I have so far (see below) which is using global variables, but this doesn't seem to work.

main.sh

```
source shared.sh

width=0
height=0

getSize "iPhone_7"

echo $width
echo $height
```

shared.sh

```
getSize() {
if [ "$1"  == "iPhone_7" ] 
   then
   $width=200
   $height=100
fi
}
```

I get the following errors..

```
bash: 0=200: command not found
bash: 0=100: command not found
0
0
```

Comment: Remove the `$` in front of assignment...

Comment: I assume `getSize` is going to be a lookup table.  I strongly encourage you to use a `case` statement rather than chained if/else.  eg `case $1 in iPhone_7) width=200; height=100;; ...`

Comment: use https://shellcheck.net to find many coding errors and save your time waiting for replies here. Be sure to include `#!/bin/bash` (or which ever shell you are using) as the first line when you paste your code there. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks guys. Could do this without global variables. Maybe with an array?